# How i can add new row into datagrid in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to Insert all Rows values of DataGrid for Once every Click of a button ,
so if user inserted three times display on datagrid three rows,I have a class there is code

```
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Job { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public MyGrid(string Vendors,string Jobs,string Tel)
    {
        Name = Vendors;
        Job = Jobs;
        Phone = Tel;
    }
```

and i called into button click event here

```
       static List<MyGrid> gride;
        gride = new List<MyGrid>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            var myg1 = new MyGrid(textBox10.Text, textBox11.Text, textBox12.Text);
            gride.Add(myg1);

        }

        dataGridView1.ItemsSource = gride;
```

this code it's working but there is the one problem,When add data is supposed to appear in a one row, but appears within 3 rows in the one click ,
I want to show one row in per click with different data .
How i can add new row  per click on the button in wpf

Comment: Why are you looping it thrice then if you want it to be added only once? Remove the for loop then.

Comment: @RohitVats When i remove the for loop the data added only once right but when i write new data and i click add button the row data changed,i want to add new row not changed at the same row

Comment: There are couple of issues in your code apart from that. I have added an answer. See if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all this is not a way to do WPF way. Use proper bindings to achieve you want.

Steps to do in WPF way:

1. Create [`ObservableCollection<MyGrid>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and bind ItemsSource with that collection.
2. Instead of setting ItemsSource again simply add object in that collection. DataGrid will be refreshed automatically since ObservableCollection implement **`INotifyCollectionChanged`**.

---

Now, for your code there are couple of issues.

1. If you want item to be added once, why to run for loop and add object thrice. **`Remove the for loop`**.
2. With every button click, you are re-initializing the list. Instead keep the list as instance field and **`initialize list only once from class constructor`**.
3. **`No need to set ItemsSource again`** with every button click.

---

```
public class CodeBehindClass
{
   private ObservableCollection<MyGrid> gride;
   public CodeBehindClass()
   {
      gride = new ObservableCollection<MyGrid>();
      dataGridView1.ItemsSource = gride;
   }

   private void ButtonHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      var myg1 = new MyGrid(textBox10.Text, textBox11.Text, textBox12.Text);
      gride.Add(myg1);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it's working now, but I have another question, how do I work looping them so I insert all rows within the database

Comment: You can use for loop then and run the loop equal to number of records in database and add them to the collection.

Comment: I have one question if you don't mind please how i can catch value cell like this dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value

Comment: You can refer to this link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/01a15d97-d321-4b93-8757-7b7b07378ee2/get-cell-value-from-wpf-datagrid-c.