# Can I use datagridview code for WPF datagrid?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, datagridview, datagrid

Here's a sample code. i want to know how you can use this code for wpf datagrid.

whenever I try this code it gets an error in the dataStudents.Rows.Add Line

```
public void LoadStudents()
            {
                dataStudents.Rows.Clear();
                dataAssStud.Rows.Clear();

                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT StudID, Lname, 
                    Fname, MI FROM Students;", con);
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    dataStudents.Rows.Add(rdr[0].ToString(), rdr[1].ToString(),
                           rdr[2].ToString(), rdr[3].ToString());
                    dataAssStud.Rows.Add(rdr[0].ToString(), rdr[1].ToString(),
                           rdr[2].ToString(), rdr[3].ToString());
                }

                con.Close();
            }
```

Comment: What is the error _exactly_? And what is `dataStudents`?

Comment: it says 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' does not contain a definition for 'Rows" and no extension method 'Rows' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' could be found( are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: dataStudents is the name of the DataGrid

Comment: I'm not familiar with WPF concept but looks like you can't add a new row to datagrid like this. Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095172/how-i-can-add-new-row-into-datagrid-in-wpf

Comment: I'm checking it now. Thanks.